# Multihomed Routing - Linux: allow traffic to be reply on another interface

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I've connected to two ISPs and announced my own IP space (/24 IPv4) to them, so both of the ISPs route the traffic destinated my subnet to my router (A Linux server).

Two ISPs are connected to the different interface on the Linux router, let's say `eth0` and `eth1`.

Now, when I try to `ping` an address, all I got is request timeout. However, by doing `tcpdump`, I can see the reply of the remote machine, but not on the same interface that Linux router send request from. (i.e. send from `eth0`, got reply on `eth1`):

eth0:

```
17:11:26.136885 IP tky01.jp.nat.moe > syr.edu: ICMP echo request, id 22910, seq 1, length 64
17:11:27.139627 IP tky01.jp.nat.moe > syr.edu: ICMP echo request, id 22910, seq 2, length 64
17:11:28.163632 IP tky01.jp.nat.moe > syr.edu: ICMP echo request, id 22910, seq 3, length 64
17:11:29.187715 IP tky01.jp.nat.moe > syr.edu: ICMP echo request, id 22910, seq 4, length 64
17:11:30.211766 IP tky01.jp.nat.moe > syr.edu: ICMP echo request, id 22910, seq 5, length 64
```

eth1:

```
17:11:26.314683 IP syr.edu > tky01.jp.nat.moe: ICMP echo reply, id 22910, seq 1, length 64
17:11:27.317398 IP syr.edu > tky01.jp.nat.moe: ICMP echo reply, id 22910, seq 2, length 64
17:11:28.341461 IP syr.edu > tky01.jp.nat.moe: ICMP echo reply, id 22910, seq 3, length 64
17:11:29.365671 IP syr.edu > tky01.jp.nat.moe: ICMP echo reply, id 22910, seq 4, length 64
17:11:30.389885 IP syr.edu > tky01.jp.nat.moe: ICMP echo reply, id 22910, seq 5, length 64
```

I tried to do policy routing:

```
ip rule add from x.x.x.x/24 lookup isp2 # where x.x.x.x is my subnet.
ip route add default via y.y.y.y dev eth1 table isp2 # where y.y.y.y is ISP2's gateway
```

That makes `ping` operate normally, but now any user choose to enter my AS using ISP1 (eth0) won't be able to reach anything.

How do I make Linux know that both `eth0` and `eth1` can reply the request?

Answer (score 2):

I have just figured it out. `rp_filter` needs to be disabled in order to allow reply from different path:

```
for iface in eth{0,1}; do echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/$iface/rp_filter; done
```

To make it permanent, set `net.ipv4.conf.<iface>.rp_filter = 0` in sysctl.